# Calculating the Kallen-Lehmann representation of conserved currents

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, greens-functions, propagator

Let $J^u$ be a complex conserved current. I want to obtain the Kallen-Lehmann representation of the vacuum expectation value $<T(J^u J^v)>_{0}$ where $T$ stands for the time ordered product.

I am stuck because I cannot figure out how to deal with conserved currents.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Källén-Lehmann_spectral_representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n-Lehmann_spectral_representation)

I tried to follow the proof in the above link but I cannt find an appropriate complete set of some vectors....

Could anyone help me?

Comment: This may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123526/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431622/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581786/226902