# An issue with spectral representation in Coleman's proof of Goldstone's theorem in his Lectures on QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, symmetry-breaking, goldstone-mode

I am working through the proof of Goldstone's theorem in Coleman's *Lectures on QFT* in chapter 43.4.

He uses a Källén-Lehmann-like spectral representation of
$$\langle 0 | j_{\mu}\left(x\right)\phi\left(y\right) |0 \rangle .\tag{43.83}$$
I understand the general logic but I do not know how to justify the presence of $k_{\mu}$ in
$$\langle 0 | j_{\mu}\left(x\right)\phi\left(y\right) |0 \rangle = \int d^4k \sigma\left(k^2\right) \theta\left(k_0\right) k_{\mu} e^{ik \cdot \left(x-y\right)}. \tag{43.84}$$
I know there ought to be a 4-vector on the RHS because the LHS is a 4-vector itself, so do we just put in $k_{\mu}$ and let $\sigma\left(k^2\right)$ "take care" of the units and possible constant factors? Or are there any deeper reasons I can't see?

Comment: This may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123526/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431622/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581786/226902.